# CSS reset and browsers dependencies

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

Can a CSS reset file eliminate the need for coding style rules for specific browsers?

For Example: `-moz-` in Firefox, `-webkit-` for Safari and Chrome, `-o-` for Opera, and `-ms-` for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what a CSS Reset stylesheet is for. A reset stylesheet is used to override existing or preset styles on a web page to their default values. This can be useful when you are using a popular framework or library that includes styling, and you wish to avoid the styling while still using the library.

It does not obviate the need for vendor-prefixes because it has no relation to what browser a visitor will use to visit your site. Any new styles you use that include vendor-prefixed properties will still need those vendor-prefixed properties.

By the way, Firefox and Microsoft Edge use some `-webkit-` prefixes, as well, for compatibility.